# On deployment the API is not showing any data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

### Intro

I had created a `NewsReaderApp` which is working fine in the local environment using [newsAPI](https://newsapi.org/).

### Problem

The problem is occurring in the deployment part, it is deployed successfully in Netlify but when I open the deployed site [click here](https://nostalgic-agnesi-31ca8f.netlify.app/) , it is showing no news articles,

ideally, it should look like this picture below

[image: err] .

This means that the API is not fetching the data. I don't know why it is happening. Even I tried to console log the `parsedData` I am not able to see the consoled stmt in the local as you can see in the pic also. I am sharing the code of the file where I am fetching the data.

#### code

**News.js**

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from "react";
import NewItem from "./NewItem";
import Spinner from "./Spinner";
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroll-component";

const News = (props) => {


  const capitilizeFirstLetter = (str) => {
    return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
  };

  const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [totalResults, setTotalResults] = useState(0);
  
  const updateNews = async() => {
    props.setProgress(10);
    const url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${props.country}&category=${props.category}&apiKey=${props.apikey}&page=${page}&pageSize=${props.pageSize || "12"}`;
    setLoading(true);
    let data = await fetch(url);
    props.setProgress(30);
    let parsedData = await data.json();
    props.setProgress(50);
    //console.log(parsedData)
    setArticles(parsedData.articles);
    setTotalResults(parsedData.totalResults);
    setLoading(false);
    props.setProgress(100);
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    updateNews();
    document.title = `NewsReader2 - ${capitilizeFirstLetter(props.category)}`;
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    //console.log("render");
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [])



  const fetchMoreData = async () => {
    let url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${props.country || "in"}&category=${props.category || "general"}&apiKey=${props.apikey}&page=${page+1}&pageSize=${props.pageSize}`;
    setPage(page+1);
    let data = await fetch(url);
    let parsedData = await data.json();
    
    console.log(parsedData)
    
    setArticles(articles?.concat(parsedData?.articles));
    setTotalResults(parsedData.totalResults);
  };

    return (
      <div style={props.darkmodeStyle}>
        <h1 className="text-center" style={{ margin: "35px 0px", marginTop:'5%' }}>
          New Reader2 
        </h1>
        <div
          className={`alert alert-${props.mode === 'light' ? 'primary':'custom'} text-center`}
          role="alert"
          style={{ fontSize: "150%", fontWeight: 700 }}
        >
          News from {capitilizeFirstLetter(props.category)} world
        </div>

        {loading && <Spinner />}

        <InfiniteScroll
          next={fetchMoreData}
          dataLength={
            articles?.length ? articles?.length : 15
          }
          hasMore={articles?.length !== totalResults}
          loader={<Spinner />}
        >
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              {articles?.map((item) => {
                return (
                  <div className="col-md-4" key={item.url}>
                    <NewItem
                      title={item.title ? item.title.slice(0, 45) : ""}
                      description={
                        item.description ? item.description.slice(0, 88) : ""
                      }
                      imageUrl={
                        item.urlToImage
                          ? item.urlToImage
                          : "https://www.eastmojo.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/space-pen-5.jpg"
                      }
                      newsUrl={item.url}
                      publishedAt={item.publishedAt}
                      author={item.author ? item.author : "Anonymous"}
                      source={item.source.name}
                      darkmodeStyle={props.darkmodeStyle}
                    />
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
        </InfiniteScroll>
      </div>
    );
  
}

export default News;
```

Please help me to find a way to deploy this app successfully?

Comment: `{"status":"error","code":"corsNotAllowed","message":"Requests from the browser are not allowed on the Developer plan, except from localhost."}`

they don't allow api calls on free plan ig

Comment: If you open your network tab you will see that the api is getting failed with `426` ERROR CODE. Also response is saying `"Requests from the browser are not allowed on the Developer plan, except from localhost."` so just take a look into the documentation/plans of api that you are consuming.

Comment: Yes, this is for development mode only. and not for production . For production, you need to subscribe the premium feature

Answer (score 2):

You have CORS issue. The API you are using worked on development because the domain `localhost` is allowed. See the image below
[image: your webaite image]
The error message is : "Requests from the browser are not allowed on the Developer plan, except from localhost."

Check out the API's docs to see what you can do. It seems that you need to pay in order to deploy your website.